# Couldn't pass the combobox value to ajax

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to pass the combobox value to ajax but couldn't do so. please help. Ajax Code is as under:

```
var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;

function showUser(val) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("sub").innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
    }
  }
  XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "get_test.php?val=" + val, true);
  XMLHttpRequestObject.send();
}
```

And Html Code is as under

```
<select name='sem' id = 'sem' style = 'margin-left: 3.4em;' class = 'shor_list'>
                <option value='Null'>------Select Semester------</option>
                <option value='1st'>1st</option>
                <option value='2nd'>2nd</option>
                <option value='3rd'>3rd</option>
                <option value='4th'>4th</option>
                <option value='5th'>5th</option>
                <option value='6th'>6th</option>
                <option value='7th'>7th</option>
                <option value='8th'>8th</option>
                </select>
<span onclick="showUser('sem.value');">update list</span>
```

But AJAX function is not receiving the id of select tag. please suggest solution

Answer (score 0):

keep this line as the first line in function showUser()

```
val = document.getElementById("sem").value;
```

the reason here is, the way you are getting the select box value is inappropriate. sending values from html elements is not a standard and must be avoided.